Will the RabbitMQ Cluster Operator ensure that RabbitMQ keeps working when K8S gets upgraded
I have followed the quick start on the RabbitMQ website here https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/quickstart-operator. It is up and running with 2 RabbitMQ cluster pods.
I have a production K8S in Azure with 4 nodes. Once in a while, the K8S cluster and the nodes need to be upgraded. This results in downtime, because my RabbitMQ instance is just one pod atm. We are in the process of implementing a zero-downtime infrastructure and we expect the RabbitMQ cluster operator adds to this.
My question; will the setup the above cluster make sure that there will always be one RabbitMQ cluster pod up and running to make sure the application stays available?
Additional question; will the operator also ensure that the RabbitMQ pods are always distributed over multiple nodes in case one node breaks down?
